# Adding Basic Authentication on the Spray Client

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am trying to set up connection with the Url from `scala/spray` code in the following way:

```
val Response = HttpDialog(Http.Connect("Url", port = 80, sslEncryption = true)).send(Get(String.format(endpoint, parameter1, parameter2))).end
```

Url expects to authenticate for which I need to add an Authorization header in the above `Http request` that contains a base64-encoded username:password string.

How to add that authorization header?

Thanks,
Arpit.

Answer (score 4):

You can transform your Get with a RequestTransformer, specifically `spray.httpx.RequestBuilding.addCredentials` .

```
val Response = HttpDialog(...).send(
  Get(String.format(endpoint, parameter1, parameter2)) ~> addCredentials(BasicHttpCredentials(username, password))
).end
```

If you peek into the source code, all it is doing is adding an HttpAuthorization header for those credentials à la the addHeader transformer.